# Ajax request : from jQuery to Angular

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

I read every threads on SO which talks about that problem, but I can't find the solution.

Here's the problem :

I have an Ajax request (get) which works with jQuery :

```
$.ajax({
dataType: 'json',
url: "/me"
}, function (d){});
```

I want to do the same thing with Angular, so I tried :

```
$http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/me',
        // dataType : 'json'
        headers: {  
        'dataType': 'application/json'
        }
        })
        .then(function(res){
        $scope.items = angular.fromJson(res.data);
        $scope.newItems = angular.fromJson(res.data);
        });
```

Everytime, I get the same error :

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

As my request return the whole view, not the json (I guess). Any ideas how to fix that ?

Comment: where is the problem... can you make request and response?

Comment: Can you provide some sample code in plunker or jsfiddle? There seems nothing to be wrong with the code you provided. Something else must be wrong. I have dozens of $http calls in my app and nothing similar has ever happened.

Comment: So you think it comes from the service (/me) and not from my call ? (I can't help you on that service, I'm not skilled on back-end technologies...)

Comment: Get a network sniffer of some kind (such as ServiceCapture or Charles) and use that to determine if the actual call coming from JQuery is different than the one coming from AngularJS.  I believe they have different default headers when doing a form post; perhaps that may also cause an issue w/ Get requests.

Comment: Thank you, I will look in this way.

Comment: Remove that "dataType" header. "datatype: json" in $.ajax is just dealing with how it processes the result. If anything, set the "Accept" header, or the "Content-Type" header.